# What is the meaning of this PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning warning from pipenv --version?

Tags: python3, 22.04, pipenv

I get this warning when I run `pipenv --version` and related commands.

```
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 1.16.0-unknown is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.43ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:116: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 1.1build1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
pipenv, version 2022.5.2
```

Comment: I am getting the exact same warning. It happens when you run `pipenv --version`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A [bug in setuptools](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/3278) seems to be causing this. There is also some discussion about this on the [pipenv's Github repository](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5075). People at those two places are giving different work-arounds. The only one that worked for me was,

```
pip install --upgrade --user setuptools==58.3.0
```

Note this is actually a downgrade. Now `pipenv --version` runs without warnings.

Comment: Thanks, I don't get the warnings anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04:

```
pip install --upgrade pipenv
```

Source: [This](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/5075#issuecomment-1256992250) GitHub comment on the pipenv repository issue linked by @scribe in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run `pip list` and look for packages with the corresponding versions with errors, in your case:

- 1.16.0-unknown
- 0.1.43ubuntu1
- 1.1build1

Upgrade the corresponding packages to newer versions, for example:
`pip install --upgrade <pkg_name>`

The error messages should go away after that.

Answer (score 0):

These warnings are caused by not PEP 440 compliant versions of those Python packages. These Ubuntu package versions need to be fixed: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1991606